# With CreateFileAsync/WriteTextASync, How to determine if the file is already in use

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, asynchronous, windows-runtime

```
public async void SaveQueue()
{
        _filedata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Queue);
        StorageFile sessionFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("Queue.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sessionFile, _filedata);
}
```

So first I am serializing a Queue, and then trying to save it to a file called Queue.txt.

However, if I am making multiple calls to SaveQueue() very quickly, I will get an "File in use" exception. Is there a way I can check to see if the file is currently being written to?

Thanks!

Comment: Even if there were, it wouldn't do you any good. Because by the time you got around to actually trying to write, some other thread could have grabbed it. See my blog entry [File.Exists is only a snapshot](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/06/27/file-exists-is-only-a-snapshot/) for further explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently does not exist a way of checking this in WinRT. A workaround is to wrap these lines in a try/catch where in your catch clause, do the processing for a "file in use".